# Will Varnish recreate cache?

Tags: nginx, varnish, cache

I want to cache pages on my nginx site for fast retrieval. Let's say every 5 hours I want to expire all the cache and have it recreated. Will Varnish make calls to the web-server and recreate cache on it's own or will it have to wait till a user requests a page?

Answer (score 2):

No, Varnish does not generate requests that re-create its caches.

You need to make a manual refresh of the pages in order to get the cache warm.

Answer (score 1):

`varnishd - HTTP accelerator daemon`, it's not it's job to handle those kind of things, but what you can do is schedule a `cron job` (using `curl`, `wget`, etc) that would trigger hitting pages that you like and `Varnish` will cache them.

`curl`:

```
[alexus@wcmisdlin02 ~]$ curl --help | grep -- '--silent'
 -s/--silent        Silent mode. Don't output anything
[alexus@wcmisdlin02 ~]$
```

`wget`:

```
[alexus@wcmisdlin02 ~]$ wget --help | grep -- '--quiet'
  -q,  --quiet               quiet (no output).
[alexus@wcmisdlin02 ~]$
```

Comment: curl or wget? I don't need the results, I just have to "call" the page and have it triggered without transferring content

Comment: @Jimbotron you can always redirect redirect output to `>/dev/null`)

Comment: Yes I can do that but it's still a waste of data transfer. Is there no way to call and abandon request?

Comment: @Jimbotron it's not a waste as `Varnish` need to preserve a copy of it for next serve it for next user, if something you just doing work on behalf of user, so that user doesn't have to wait for the backend.